# Liferay 6.1 + Spring MVC Portlet 4.0: Friendly URL Mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm trying to get friendly URL mapping to work for a Spring MVC portlet inside Liferay 6.1 and fail.

My additions to the `liferay-portlet-xml` are according to the manual and blog examples available and as follows:

```
<friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
<friendly-url-mapping>search</friendly-url-mapping>
<friendly-url-routes>com/.../friendly-url-routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
```

with the `friendly-url-routes.xml` being

```
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN"
          "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">
<routes>
  <route>
    <pattern>/{match}</pattern>
    <generated-parameter name="foo">{match}</generated-parameter>
  </route>
</routes>
```

My Spring MVC controller goes like

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class CarModelController {

  @ActionMapping
  public void action(@RequestParam("foo") final String testParam,
            final ActionRequest request, final ActionResponse response) {
    this.logger.info("default action");
    this.logger.info("testParam = {}", testParam);
  }

  @RenderMapping
  public String render(final RenderRequest request, final RenderResponse response) {
    this.logger.info("default render");
    return "index";
  }
}
```

If I call my portlet using `/baseurl/-/search/bar` only the render phase output occurs, the action method isn't called.

If I create a link to this page using

```
<portlet:actionURL var="lastStepUrl">
  <portlet:param name="foo" value="bar" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

the URL Liferay generates looks like `/baseurl/-/search/bar?p_auth=sometoken&p_p_lifecycle=1`. It executes the action phase correctly and I'm also able to call that URL directly. It does, however, include the `p_auth` and `p_p_lifecycle` parameters that I want to get rid of.

Any suggestions are welcomed warmly.

Comment: I don't know Liferay, but I would start by seeing what is happening in the POST/GET that the `portlet:actionUrl` is generating as apposed to what happens when you call it directly using something like Chrome's dev tools or FireFox's FireBug.  You could then use something curl, start with an exact copy of the request that works, then start removing things until it stops working.  This would identify what is causing one request to trigger and another to not.  Things to look for: HTTP Request Type (POST/GET/etc.), any headers being sent, any POST/GET vars being sent, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Friendly URL in Liferay.
But I believe you can't completely remove `p_p_lifecycle` from url because.

this parameter tells Liferay which action to perform. This paramater has two values (0 or 1).

- 0 tells Liferay to just render the portlet,
- whereas 1 tells Liferay to call the process Action Method.

Lets say you want to remove from certain action URL then can do it like this

```
<pattern>"your URL pattern"</pattern>
<implicit-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle">1</implicit-parameter>
<implicit-parameter name="javax.portlet.action">"Your action"</implicit-parameter>
```

As we know 1 for action phase we can hard code and put it into `routes.xml` file.same way for any render URL we can put 0

To remove `p_auth` try putting below properties in `portal-ext.properties` file

```
portlet.add.default.resource.check.enabled=false
auth.token.check.enabled=false
```

Comment: I cofirm, after putting these lines in portal-ext.properties ist p_auth no more present in url.